# android checking internet connection when a button is pressed

Tags: android

i ask the same question previously but could not find a proper solution.my problem is that i want to show an messege if there is no internet connection if the web view loads and also at the same time if i press the refresh button in the android action bar..it is not displaying the toast if  i press the refresh button.can someone plse help me??

this is my connection class

```
public class Datacon extends Activity {
    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

this is mywebview.java

```
public class Mywebpage<Bitmap> extends Activity {
 String url;
  WebView myWebView ;

  ProgressBar loadingProgressBar,loadingTitle;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final Context context = this;
setContentView(R.layout.webviewpage);
AdView ads=(AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adViewer);
AdRequest request=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
ads.loadAd(request);
View mActionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_actionbar, null);
final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 
actionBar.setCustomView(mActionBarView);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradientwhite));
Button refresh = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.but2);

Button search = (Button) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
Intent inte=new Intent(Mywebpage.this,MainActivity.class);
inte.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(inte);
    finish();
    }
    })    ;


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String title;

if (!Datacon.checkInternetConnection(this)) {

    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
          Toast.makeText(this, "Check your Internet Connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} else {

if (extras != null) {
    title = extras.getString("title");
    url = extras.getString("url");
    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(title);
    myWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); 
    loadingProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1); 

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });


    refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = con_manager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();
            String status = netInfo.getState().toString();
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("CONNECTED")) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);

            }

            else  {

                Context context_new = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Hello n!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context_new, text,
                        duration);
                toast.show();

            }

        }
    });



    }
}
}
}
```

it is not showing the toast messege when refresh button is pressed if there is no internet connection..

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: its not showing the toast message when the refresh button is pressed..

Comment: Means you shut down the internet right and then checked the toast with message no Internet connection is not shown

Comment: yes the toast is not showing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your refresh button click event like below:

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Datacon.checkInternetConnection(Mywebpage.this)) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);

            }

            else  {

                Context context_new = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Hello n!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context_new, text,
                        duration);
                toast.show();

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: no its showing The method checkInternetConnection(Context) in the type Datacon is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: one more question the toast is working perfectly in devices.but its not showing in emulator..why??

Comment: @Thusharaprasad It may happen if Emulator can not get Internet or it may can not stopped the internet. But its not to worry, if its working on device then its fine.

Answer (score 0):

I checked like this, Create a class

```
public class Netconnection {

public static boolean isOnline(Context ctx) {

    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    if (ctx != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {

                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedWifi = true;
                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                    if (ni.isConnected())
                        haveConnectedMobile = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
}
```

Then check whether the network is available or not from your activity class

```
    Button homeBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    homeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (Netconnection.isOnline(Activity.this)) {
                         // Success
               }
               else
              {
                       // Display Toast
              }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can call this in your button click event also... see modified code

Answer (score 0):

//***Use the method checkConnectivity***

```
public void onClick(View view){
      checkConnectivity() 
        //do something 

        }
```

//***Method to check your connectivity***

```
private int checkConnectivity() {
        boolean enabled = true;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if ((info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable())) {
            internet = 0;//sin conexion
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sin conexión a Internet...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            enabled = false;
        } else {
            internet = 1;//conexión
        }

        return internet;
    }
```